# PHP: cant insert a value of 0 (zero)

Tags: php

hello guys I have a problem when I am inserting with a value of zero.

when I am trying to insert a zero value in [score] field it returning me with this result

[image: ss]

additional info:
the data type of [score] field is int

and here is my code:

```
<?php

    require("config.inc.php");
    if(!empty($_POST)){

            if(empty($_POST['quiz_list_id']) || empty($_POST['stud_name']) || empty($_POST['score']) || empty($_POST['term']) || empty($_POST['quiz_date'])){
                $response["Success"] = 0;
                $response["Message"] = "Please complete all fields.";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }

            $query = "SELECT 3 FROM tb_quiz WHERE quiz_list_id = :quiz_list_id AND stud_name = :stud_name AND term = :term";
            $query_params = array(
                                    ':quiz_list_id'=> $_POST['quiz_list_id'],
                                    ':stud_name'=> $_POST['stud_name'],
                                    ':term'=> $_POST['term']
                                    );

            try{
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex){
                $response["Success"] = 0;
                $response["Message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again...";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
                if($row){
                    $response["Success"] = 0;
                    $response["Message"] = "I'm sorry, this Record is already existed.";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }

                $query = "INSERT INTO tb_quiz (quiz_list_id, stud_name, score, equivalent, term, quiz_date) VALUES(:quiz_list_id, :stud_name, :score, :equivalent, :term, :quiz_date)";
                $query_params = array(
                                        ':quiz_list_id'=> $_POST['quiz_list_id'],
                                        ':stud_name' => $_POST['stud_name'],
                                        ':score' => $_POST['score'],
                                        ':equivalent' => $_POST['equivalent'],
                                        ':term'=> $_POST['term'],
                                        ':quiz_date'=> $_POST['quiz_date']

                                      );
            try{
                        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                }
                catch(PDOException $ex){
                    $response["Success"] = 0;
                    $response["Message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again...";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }
                    $response["Success"] = 1;
                    $response["Message"] = "Quiz Successfully Recorded.";
                    echo json_encode($response);

    }else{
?>

        <form action="addQuiz.php" method="post">
        Quiz List: <input type="text" name="quiz_list_id"><br>
        Stud Name: <input type="text" name="stud_name"><br>
        Score: <input type="text" name="score"><br>
        Equivalent: <input type="text" name="equivalent"><br>
        Term: <input type="text" name="term"><br>
        Date: <input type="text" name="quiz_date"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`empty()` function consider zero empty, so it return TRUE.

**The following things are considered to be empty:**

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

here is fixed code:
you can use this condition:

```
$_POST['score'] == ""
```

Here is the full code

```
<?php

    require("config.inc.php");
    if(!empty($_POST)){

            if(empty($_POST['quiz_list_id']) || empty($_POST['stud_name']) || $_POST['score'] == "" || empty($_POST['term']) || empty($_POST['quiz_date'])){
                $response["Success"] = 0;
                $response["Message"] = "Please complete all fields.";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }

            $query = "SELECT 3 FROM tb_quiz WHERE quiz_list_id = :quiz_list_id AND stud_name = :stud_name AND term = :term";
            $query_params = array(
                                    ':quiz_list_id'=> $_POST['quiz_list_id'],
                                    ':stud_name'=> $_POST['stud_name'],
                                    ':term'=> $_POST['term']
                                    );

            try{
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            }
            catch(PDOException $ex){
                $response["Success"] = 0;
                $response["Message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again...";
                die(json_encode($response));
            }

            $row = $stmt->fetch();
                if($row){
                    $response["Success"] = 0;
                    $response["Message"] = "I'm sorry, this Record is already existed.";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }

                $query = "INSERT INTO tb_quiz (quiz_list_id, stud_name, score, equivalent, term, quiz_date) VALUES(:quiz_list_id, :stud_name, :score, :equivalent, :term, :quiz_date)";
                $query_params = array(
                                        ':quiz_list_id'=> $_POST['quiz_list_id'],
                                        ':stud_name' => $_POST['stud_name'],
                                        ':score' => $_POST['score'],
                                        ':equivalent' => $_POST['equivalent'],
                                        ':term'=> $_POST['term'],
                                        ':quiz_date'=> $_POST['quiz_date']

                                      );
            try{
                        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
                }
                catch(PDOException $ex){
                    $response["Success"] = 0;
                    $response["Message"] = "Database Error1. Please Try Again...";
                    die(json_encode($response));
                }
                    $response["Success"] = 1;
                    $response["Message"] = "Quiz Successfully Recorded.";
                    echo json_encode($response);

    }else{
?>

        <form action="addQuiz.php" method="post">
        Quiz List: <input type="text" name="quiz_list_id"><br>
        Stud Name: <input type="text" name="stud_name"><br>
        Score: <input type="text" name="score"><br>
        Equivalent: <input type="text" name="equivalent"><br>
        Term: <input type="text" name="term"><br>
        Date: <input type="text" name="quiz_date"><br>
        <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
    }


?>
```

Comment: I think an explanation why your code works and the original doesn't (i.e. what was wrong) would amke your answer mcuh better.

Comment: @Burki Thank you, I will explain it.

Answer (score 1):

All variations of `0` - both `0` as integer and `"0"` as string are considered `empty`.

So `empty("0")` will return `true`. In your case I suppose you'd better compare your values with `""` (empty string)

```
if ($_POST['score'] != "") // for example
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used `empty()` to check `$_POST['score']` and its definition is -

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

You should use `isset()` instead of `empty()` or use parameter as string like below :

```
empty("$_POST['score']")
```